# How to show datatable from mysql to asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Here  is the code i make, and plese help me to create function to show datatable when i click the button.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    str = "Select count(name) as total, sum(case when status = 'DONE' then 1 else 0 end) as total_done, sum(case when status = 'PROGRESS' then 1 else 0 end) as total_progress from person where name = 'RAKA'";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, con);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        tot1.Text = reader["total"].ToString();
        done1.Text = reader["total_done"].ToString();
        prgs1.Text = reader["total_progress"].ToString();
        tb1. = reader["total"].ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: You've provided some code here that takes data from the DB and displays it on your page. Is there something not working about it? Do you get an error? Please be specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: i can not show the data to table from localhost mysql

Comment: You said all that in the question, so repeating yourself doesn't really help. The problem is that we are not at your computer. We can't see your database or code or output. It's up to you to describe all of this sufficiently, so that we will have enough info to be able to help you. We need a [MCVE]. Please edit your question to show an example of the data you're selecting from, show the relevant .aspx markup, include info about any errors you're receiving, and indicate exactly which data and which table you're trying to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in most cases to display some data, you don't need a loop.

However, you do want to use say a gridview (which is table anyway - just with nice fancy and easy to use asp.net stuff wrapped around it).

So, say you have this markup:

```
    <div style="padding:35px;width:40%">

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table">
        </asp:GridView>
        
    </div>
```

So, now in the code behind, to load this grid (table) up, you can use this code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = 
            "Select count(name) as total, sum(case when status = 'DONE' then 1 else 0 end) as total_done, " 
            + "sum(case when status = 'PROGRESS' then 1 else 0 end) as total_progress from person where name = 'RAKA'";

        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }

        // now send data table to grid view

        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

So, you want using System.Data - that is the basic table and rows and operations. That part (ado.net) is the basic objects you need. You then adopt your "provider".

for exmaple, I don't have MySQL installed, but I using sql server. So ONLY the provider part need be change.

So with above markup, I can fill out the gridview like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Fighers";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I now see/get this on the page:

[image]

but, often I will use the wizards to create the grid, and then REMOVE the data source on teh page, and use my above code. (I use the wizrard to setup the grid view, since I am lazy.

But, lets tweak up the gird. I don't want "ID", and the path name to the image, lets drop in a iamge control.

So, my markup now becomes this:

```
    <div style="padding:35px;width:50%">
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table"  >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" width="150px"
                    ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' />  />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And the code can be as before.

So, I added a image control to the grid, and a button.

So now we see/get this:

[image]

Again, note how we did NOT use a loop. But we fill out a table, and then send that table to the grid view.

And the above idea quite much applies to any kind of repeating data.

So, you can use  repeater, a Gridview, listview, datalist view etc. You can feed such controls "repeating" data, and thus no need for some loop to try and fill out controls. (and if you need repeating data, then how do you add more controls to the page - that's too hard. So, use the data aware controls, and they will render that type of data for you, especially for repeating types of data.